# How to exclude dojo files from a layer when creating a DOJO custom build?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I need exclude `dojo` dependencies from a layer.

Basically, `app/Message.js` contain two reference to dojo `["dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/topic"]` but I need to keep out `dojo` code in the layer created buy the builder.

At the moment I am using the following code but I receive an error:

> error(304) Missing exclude module for layer.  missing:
>   dojo/_base/declare; layer: app/app    missing: dojo/topic; layer:
>   app/app

Could you please point me out in the right direction and solve that error?

Notes: I am using `dojo` 1.10

```
var profile = {
        basePath: "../src/",
        action: "release",
        cssOptimize: "comments",
        mini: true,
        useSourceMaps: false,
        optimize: "closure",
        layerOptimize: "closure",
        packages: ["app"],
        stripConsole: "all",
        selectorEngine: "lite",
        layers: {
            "dojo/dojo": {
                boot: true,
                customBase: true
            },
            "app/app": {
                include: ["app/Message","app/Sender"],
                exclude: ["dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/topic"]
            }
        },
        staticHasFeatures: {
            "dojo-trace-api": !1,
            "dojo-log-api": !1,
            "dojo-publish-privates": !1,
            "dojo-sync-loader": !1,
            "dojo-xhr-factory": !1,
            "dojo-test-sniff": !1
        }
    };
```

Comment: Related documentation: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/build/transforms/writeAmd.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to list dojo in your packages as well as any other libraries you want to build into your layers.

```
var profile = {
    ...
    packages: ["app","dojo"],
    ...
};
```